# Using Vue Custom Components in Laravel Spark

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-spark

I'm pretty new to using browserify etc. for js development. Also I'm new to Vue. I wanted to create additional custom components for my application. However I fail at so many points even when following different tutorials step by step.

This is What I currently got:

**example.js**

```
var MyComponent = Vue.extend({
  data: function() {
    return { message: 'This is a test' }
  },

    template: '{{ message }}'
  });

Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent);

new Vue({
  el: '#example'
});
```

**app.js**

```
require('spark-bootstrap');

require('./../example.js');

require('./components/bootstrap');

require('./backoffice/main.js');

var app = new Vue({
    mixins: [require('spark')]
});
```

**view.blade.php**

```
<div id="example">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
       .browserify('app.js', null, null, { paths: 'vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js' })
       .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js', 'public/js/sweetalert.min.js')
       .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css', 'public/css/sweetalert.css');
});
```

My error

```
app.js:24638[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-component> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `example.js` is a separate module, you'll need to import Vue in that file as well.  I assume you've done that.  You also don't want to `new` up a Vue instance in that file though, because you're already doing that later on.  If `<my-component>` is inside of the spark body you already have a Vue app running.